# how to publish ASP.NET web api from internet modem's port

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, rethinkdb

I want to publish my web api from my internet modem. With this, my android app(rest client) can send HTTP requests.

This is for an android app-realtime DB connection, i use RethinkDB. I tried ngrok to publish but my realtime DB is running on local. When i use ngrok web api can not see my DB that running on local.

I expect manipulating the DB from android app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If both your mobile and system are on the same network, try accessing API through your system IP. This has got to do something with your firewall. You can also host your webapi in IIS and try reaching by system IP. 
Ps: Add an unauthorized GET method and test from your mobile browser

Comment: If i host my web api with IIS, can it reach-and get HTTP result- my db that running on localhost 8080 port ?

Comment: Yes, why not. Host your webapi and give it a shot. It must work

Comment: I dont know how to use system IP on reaching API from app, can you explain shortly or give a link about that.